# Accessing a generator created Using AsyncIO

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, httpx

I am trying to follow this [tutorial][1], but use asyncio instead. I am stuck on the one part in the main function where I put the tasks in the list and then gather them in the results variable. I imagine that this is each of the pages. I want to use the following parse function to extract all the item information from each page

```py
from typing import Any
import asyncio
import httpx

from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.parse import urljoin


async def fetch_html(client: httpx.AsyncClient, url: str, **kwargs) -> Any:
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": **"Add yours or you will get a 403"**
    }

    if kwargs.get("page"):
        resp = await client.get(
            url=url + str(kwargs.get("page")), follow_redirects=True, headers=headers
        )

    else:
        resp = await client.get(url=url, follow_redirects=True, headers=headers)

    try:
        resp.raise_for_status()
    except httpx.HTTPStatusError as exc:
        print(
            f"Error response {exc.response.status_code} while requesting {exc.request.url!r}. Page limit exceeded"
        )
        return False

    html = HTMLParser(html=resp.text)
    return html


def extract_text(html: HTMLParser, sel: str):
    try:
        text = html.css_first(sel).text()
        return text
    except AttributeError:
        return None


def parse_search_page(html: HTMLParser):
    products = html.css("li.VcGDfKKy_dvNbxUqm29K")
    for product in products:
        yield urljoin("https://www.rei.com/", product.css_first("a").attributes["href"])


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:
        tasks = []
        rei_url = "https://www.rei.com/c/camping-and-hiking/f/scd-deals?page="
        for i in range(1, 2):
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch_html(client, rei_url, page=i)))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks) # print statement calls this [<HTMLParser chars=1437412>] so I thought this was an HTMLParser object that I can acesss in the following function

    links = parse_search_page(results) # Argument of type "list[Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "html" of type "HTMLParser" in function "parse_search_page"
    for link in links:
        print(link)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I am getting an Attribute error. My ideal data would have the results and then I would be able to loop through it with the parse page function (which itself is a generator that I can loop through). That is the mental model I have currently. I have tried putting both in the create task, making the parse function async, but that didn't seem to make sense. I am not
[1]: https://youtu.be/DHvzCVLv_FA?si=9qJeqLmI02iYSCkA

Answer (score 0):

You get a generator which is an iterable object. You just need to iterate through it and store the results somewhere (this is shown with the two lists in the main function). I also pulled some logic out of the main function so that it is more dynamic. If there's a cleaner way to do it that will be greatly appreciated.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable
from time import perf_counter
from typing import Any
import asyncio
import httpx
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, fields

from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.parse import urljoin


@dataclass
class Item:
    name: str | None
    item_num: str | None
    price: str | None
    rating: float | None
    image_link: str | None


async def fetch_html(client: httpx.AsyncClient, url: str, **kwargs) -> Any:
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": **Add your own headers**
    }

    if kwargs.get("page"):
        resp = await client.get(
            url=url + str(kwargs.get("page")), follow_redirects=True, headers=headers
        )

    else:
        resp = await client.get(url=url, follow_redirects=True, headers=headers)

    try:
        resp.raise_for_status()
    except httpx.HTTPStatusError as exc:
        print(
            f"Error response {exc.response.status_code} while requesting {exc.request.url!r}. Page limit exceeded"
        )
        return False

    html = HTMLParser(html=resp.text)
    return html


def parse_search_page(html: HTMLParser):
    products = html.css("li.VcGDfKKy_dvNbxUqm29K")
    for product in products:
        yield urljoin("https://www.rei.com/", product.css_first("a").attributes["href"])


def parse_item_page(html: HTMLParser):
    new_item = Item(
        name=extract_text(html, "h1#product-page-title"),
        item_num=extract_text(html, "span#product-item-number"),
        price=extract_text(html, "span#buy-box-product-price"),
        rating=extract_text(html, "span.cdr-rating__number_13-5-3"),
        image_link=html.css_first("img").attributes["src"],
    )
    return asdict(new_item)


def extract_text(html: HTMLParser, sel: str) -> Any:
    try:
        text = html.css_first(sel).text()
        return text
    except AttributeError:
        return None


async def fetch_all_pages(
    client: httpx.AsyncClient, url: str, page_range: Iterable[int], **kwargs
):
    tasks = []
    for page_num in page_range:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(fetch_html(client, url, page=page_num)))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True) as client:
        item_page_links = []
        item_desc = []

        page_range = range(1, 2)
        rei_url = "https://www.rei.com/c/camping-and-hiking/f/scd-deals?page="

        start_time = perf_counter()
        top_level_html = await fetch_all_pages(client, rei_url, page_range)

        for page in top_level_html:
            item_page_links = parse_search_page(page)

        for link in item_page_links:
            print(link)
            item_html = await fetch_html(client, link)
            item_desc.append(parse_item_page(item_html))

        print(item_desc)
        end_time = perf_counter()
        print(f"Total time to scrape:{end_time - start_time} ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```